# What is a transverse pointer cast?

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance

I encountered this in Horstmann's Core Java, Volume 1:

> C++ has multiple inheritance and all the compications that come with it, such as virtual base classes, dominance rules, and transverse pointer casts...

Core Java Volume I: Fundamentals [Horstmann, Cay S. 2016 Prentice Hall 10th ed. §6.1.3 p. 297]

Now, I am familiar with the other two, but what is a transverse pointer cast? Is it the term for casting a pointer to a base class as a derived class?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't learn C++ from a Java person's rant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen the term before, but I reckon this is another name for a *cross-cast*, when you need to cast "across" (rather than "up" or "down") an inheritance graph. Take the following situation:

```
// V-shaped inheritance graph

// [ Base1 ]   [ Base2 ]
//      \         /
//       \       /
//      [ Derived ]

struct Base1 { };
struct Base2 { };
struct Derived : Base1, Base2 { };

// ...

// Take an object of derived type
Derived d;

// Upwards conversion, we get its Base1 subobject
Base1 *b1 = &d;
```

Now suppose we only have `b1`, of static type `Base1` and dynamic type `Derived`, and we want to reach the `Base2` subobject, that is, convert *across* the V's branches.

The issue is, we lost the information that `*b1` is actually a subobject of a `Derived`. It could be a subobject of any other class, or an object on its own. We have to use one of two tools:

```
// If we know by other means that b1 is for sure a Derived,
// walk the graph explicitly through Derived
Base2 *b2 = /* implicit upwards conversion */ static_cast<Derived*>(b1);

// If Base1 is polymorphic (i.e. has at least one virtual function)
// Let RTTI do the job and check for errors. Slower but safer.
Base2 *b2 = dynamic_cast<Base2 *>(b1);
```